# Nest of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the difference about the constructs below?:

A: Mutiple UINavigationController.

```
UINavigationController
`——UITabBarController
        |——UINavigationController
        |   `——UIViewController
        |——UINavigationController
        |   `——UIViewController
        |——UINavigationController
        |   `——UIViewController
        `——UINavigationController
            `——UIViewController
```

B: Single line UINavigationController.

```
UITabBarController
    |——UINavigationController
    |   `——UIViewController
    |——UINavigationController
    |   `——UIViewController
    |——UINavigationController
    |   `——UIViewController
    `——UINavigationController
        `——UIViewController
```

C: Single UINavigationController.

```
UINavigationController
`----UITabBarController
    |——UIViewController
    |——UIViewController
    |——UIViewController
    `——UIViewController
```

Comment: Some clarification is needed here. What problem are you trying to solve, or what architecture are you trying to create? What behaviour do you expect from one or any of these arrangements?

Comment: If you are creating Tabbar based application then option B will be perfect for it. Option A and C seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's incorrect to use multiple navigation in your controller hierarchy. You will meet the error when you push a navigation to an exist navigation:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`